# Changing line spacing within a new command

Tags: macros, line-spacing, setspace

I have a command written as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{setspace}

\newcommand{\statshyp}[2]{\noindent \hangindent=1cm \hangafter=0 
\begin{singlespace*}
\textbf{#1}: \emph{#2}
\end{singlespace*}
}
```

Unfortunately, changing the line spacing just within the new command doesn't work. The intention is to create a macro which allows me to create identically formatted single-spaced hypotheses in a generally doublespaced document. Is there a way to do this? I found one other person asking a similar question but the answers given to him provided a way for him to get what he needed without using the spacing commands at all.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 2):

This might be something near to what you want; but the result is not pretty (nothing with very large interline space can be).

I don't think that a length such as 1cm is good: it doesn't mix with the other parameters. Perhaps more space would be needed around the single spaced insertion.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{setspace,lipsum,changepage}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{singlespace*}
  {\setstretch {\setspace@singlespace}%
   \vskip -\baselineskip}
  {\vskip -.25\baselineskip}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\statshyp}[2]{%
  \begin{singlespace*}
  \begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{0pt}
  \noindent\textbf{#1}: \emph{#2} \par
  \end{adjustwidth}
  \end{singlespace*}
}

\onehalfspacing
\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\statshyp{Some}{I don't know what to say, but I'm
trying to keep it very long so that it wraps and
the paragraph will show the effect of the parameters.}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.

Not to be greedy, but is there a way to do it without redefining singlespace? I would like to use the command normally elsewhere ... 

I promise to contribute back to the board later, answering questions that I can in gratitude for the questions answered.

Comment: @Ennis Alternating single with double spacing needs careful setting of the parameters; the attempt made by `setspace` with the `singlespacing*` environment fails to give symmetric spaces, so adjustments are necessary. Of course the best is *not* using double spacing.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\doublespacing
\newcommand\statshyp[2]{%
\noindent\parbox{\textwidth}{\singlespacing\textbf{#1}: \emph{#2}}
~\par%
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\statshyp{Hypothesis}{This is my hypothesis:  that I can insert
single-spaced stuff.  This line must be long enough to extend over
multiple lines.  This should be enough for the test}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]